# "Application or Object Defined Error" When Assigning a Cell's Column Value to a Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure why VBA says "Application or Object Defined Error" when I try to run this. I have tried to make sure the data types are consistent and the syntax is correct, but I am very new to VBA so I can't seem to spot the error. Here is what the code is trying to do:

1. Find the range of cells containing a list of dates along row 3 (Dates = ....). This part is working fine.
2. Loop through the dates and match the input date to the range of dates. This part is also fine.
3. When the date is found, give the column of the current cell to the integer variable 'Col'.

Step 3 is where the error occurs. It highlights the "Col =..." and spits the error. As you can tell, I have tried multiple ways to do it (commented out one of them) without any luck.

Any help is appreciated. I know there are more efficient ways to find the column but I would like to make this work.

```
Sub get_col(input_date As Date)

Dim Lastcol As Integer
Dim Dates As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim address As Integer
Dim Col As Integer

Lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set Dates = Range(Cells(3, 12), Cells(3, Lastcol))


For Each Cell In Dates
    If Cell.Value = input_date Then
       'Col = ActiveSheet.Cells([INDIRECT(Cell.address]).Column
        Col = ActiveSheet.Range("Cell").Column
    End If
Next

Range("C1") = Col

End Sub
```

Comment: `Col = Cell.Column` Also you may want to add `Exit For` after that line.

Comment: You define `Cell` as range type variable but pass as string. So use `Col` like what @SiddharthRout suggested.

Comment: @Harun Thanks, that makes sense... Any idea why the indirect method doesn't work?

Comment: @k.ali May bracketing problem. And for worksheet function you have use `Application.Worksheetfunction.Indirect()`.